# Perl regex for whole word match containing special character û

Tags: regex, string, perl

In Perl 5.8.5, I need to write a regular expression that should match a whole word containing extended latin1 character set.  If I write it like this "\b\w+\b", it breaks, if it encounters a character like this 'û'.

What is needed to ensure that whole word match using regular expression in Perl 5.8.5 works towards the Latin1 (ISO8859-1) character set, including all extended characters?

Perl is installed in CentOS 4.6.  The locale command in Linux gives the following output:

```
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

For a given word, eg. "abc grûler xyz", the regex towards a whole word match for string "gr" shouldn't be searched, which is searched in my case being a substring of the word "grûler". The regex is:

```
$string =~ /\b\w+\b/;
```

The output is "gr", which is incorrect, since it is a substring as said.

Also, I don't want to exclude extended characters completely from being matched.  If a match is needed towards the whole word "grûler", then it should also work fine with the same regex.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You're using Perl 5.8.5 which is a very old version of Perl. I'm not sure how that version of Perl is with unicode support. Perldoc's webpage doesn't go that far back, and I can't install it via Perlbrew. Is it possible to update to a newer version of Perl?

Comment: If you decode your input, even if it's iso-8859-1, it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by ikegami, you've probably simply not decoded your input.
Consider indeed this one-liner (on an UTF-8 terminal):

```
echo "abc grûler xyz" | perl -Mopen=:std,:utf8 -le '$,="\n"; print <> =~ /\b\w+\b/g'
```

which gives the expected matches:

```
abc
grûler
xyz
```

since it decodes the input string before the match, thanks to `-Mopen=:std,:utf8` (which then also causes the output to be encoded).
You can obtain the same via explicit decoding/encoding (through [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode), among others).

Now remove `-Mopen=:std,:utf8` from the one-liner above and you'll get the same unexpected match (on the 'gr' substring) you described.

More on this: [The "Unicode Bug"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#The-%22Unicode-Bug%22).

I don't know if a perl this old has additional problems though (perl 5.8.8 should work).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `use locale` to have locale-sensitive regexes. This affects lots of other Perl aspects as well though, so you might not want to enable it globally. See the `perllocale` documentation.